# Как адаптировать картинки slick sliderа на на полный экран на всех разрешениях без искажений?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, slick.js

Есть адаптивный `slick` слайдер, у которого слайды должны занимать ровно весь экран (по ширине и высоте), а по горизонтальному и вертикальному центру - подложка с текстом.

Причем, картинка не должна искажаться (растягиваться или сужаться)

На больших разрешениях все выглядит у меня хорошо, а вот на мобильном -  образуются белые полосы сверху и снизу. 
Как добиться правильного отображения на всех экранах?

Код и [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/56xk12yz/)

```js
$('#home-slider').slick({
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

```css
#home-slider {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide,
#home-slider .slick-track {
  height: 100vh;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide img {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper,
.block-wrapper-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper {
  height: 66.7vh;
}

.block-wrapper-heading {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block-wrapper-text p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="home-slider">
  <div>
    <div class="block-wrapper-slider text-center">
      <img src="https://static9.depositphotos.com/1000803/1136/i/950/depositphotos_11362153-stock-photo-street-ice-cream-cafe.jpg">
      <div class="block-wrapper-heading">
        <h2>Это крутое заведение!</h2>
        <p><i>Здесь самое вкусное мороженное</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="block-wrapper-slider text-center">
      <img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1585997/7685/i/950/depositphotos_76851169-stock-photo-waiters-serving-food-and-drinks.jpg">
      <div class="block-wrapper-heading">
        <h2>КАЧЕСТВО - НАШ ГЛАВНЫЙ ПРИОРИТЕТ!</h2>
        <p><i>Мы используем лучшие ингредиенты и уникальные технологии.</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Использовать `object-fit: cover` или сделать свой аналог для лучшей поддержки. Но, в таком случае картинки будут обрезаться.

Comment: @E_K да, у `object-fit` пока очень плохая поддержка. Да пусть обрезается, я не против - а что такое свой аналог?

Comment: Использовать изображения не через `img`, а как фон или если нужен тег `img` то с помощью `position` разместить блок с картинкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вариант с фоном.

```js
$('#home-slider').slick({
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

```css
#home-slider {
  height: 100vh;
  //margin-bottom: 80px;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide,
#home-slider .slick-track {
  height: 100vh;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide img {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper,
.block-wrapper-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper {
  height: 66.7vh;
}

.block-wrapper-heading {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block-wrapper-text p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/*UPD.*/
.block-wrapper-slider {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="home-slider">
  <div>
    <div class="block-wrapper-slider text-center" style="background-image: url('https://static9.depositphotos.com/1000803/1136/i/950/depositphotos_11362153-stock-photo-street-ice-cream-cafe.jpg')">
      <div class="block-wrapper-heading">
        <h2>Это крутое заведение!</h2>
        <p><i>Здесь самое вкусное мороженное</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="block-wrapper-slider text-center" style="background-image: url('https://st2.depositphotos.com/1585997/7685/i/950/depositphotos_76851169-stock-photo-waiters-serving-food-and-drinks.jpg')">
      <div class="block-wrapper-heading">
        <h2>КАЧЕСТВО - НАШ ГЛАВНЫЙ ПРИОРИТЕТ!</h2>
        <p><i>Мы используем лучшие ингредиенты и уникальные технологии.</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Вариант с тегом

```js
$('#home-slider').slick({
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 4000,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

```css
#home-slider {
  height: 100vh;
  //margin-bottom: 80px;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide,
#home-slider .slick-track {
  height: 100vh;
}

#home-slider .slick-slide img {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper,
.block-wrapper-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper {
  height: 66.7vh;
}

.block-wrapper-heading {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.block-wrapper-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.block-wrapper-text p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/*UPD*/

.block-wrapper-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block__img-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.block__img-wrapper img {
  width: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 90rem) {
  .block__img-wrapper img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="home-slider">
  <div>
    <div class="block-wrapper-slider text-center">
      <div class="block__img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://static9.depositphotos.com/1000803/1136/i/950/depositphotos_11362153-stock-photo-street-ice-cream-cafe.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="block-wrapper-heading">
        <h2>Это крутое заведение!</h2>
        <p><i>Здесь самое вкусное мороженное</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="block-wrapper-slider text-center">
      <div class="block__img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1585997/7685/i/950/depositphotos_76851169-stock-photo-waiters-serving-food-and-drinks.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="block-wrapper-heading">
        <h2>КАЧЕСТВО - НАШ ГЛАВНЫЙ ПРИОРИТЕТ!</h2>
        <p><i>Мы используем лучшие ингредиенты и уникальные технологии.</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если с тегом, но обрезав изображение? Я пробую позиционировать, но пока не совсем получается
http://jsfiddle.net/56xk12yz/1/

Comment: @Вася у вас два варианта, изображение обрезается или растягивается. По другому никак. Пропорции экранов и изображения разные. Поэтому на ПК нормально, а на смартофонах по другому.

Comment: пусть обрезается, это нормально. Просто, если выполнить ваш второй вариант - почему-то картинка показывается только на половину ширины - так и задумано или редактор косячит и на мобильнике будет по-другому?

Comment: @Вася, поправил пример.